# Expand child height based on taller sibling (parent height set to auto)

Tags: html, css

Simple question **(snippet below)**:

- `<ul>` with `display: flex`
- each `<li>` should have the same size and together must occupy the full width of the `<ul>`
- each `<li>` has a `<a>` which the content may have 1 or 2 lines of text.
- each `<li>` has **height set to auto** to adjust to the `<a>` content

[image]

**My problem:**

I need the "one-line" links to auto expand to the height of the "two-line" links. Setting `height: 100%` doesn't work because their parent `height` it's intentionally set to auto to adjust for content.

But in some cases I'll get two-line links, and some cases all will be one-line. So I need the one-line links to auto-expand when that happens.

How is this possible?

```css
#root {
  width: 140px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 30px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  height: auto;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px dotted green;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 8px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <ul>
    <li><a>Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a>Long Link 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;` on a ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `inline-block` with flex. Just use `display: flex` for `li` and `display: block` for `a`. Finally, add the `width: 100%` for `a`. It seems match your requirement.

```css
#root {
  width: 140px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 30px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  height: auto;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px dotted green;
  display: block;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 8px 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <ul>
    <li><a>Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a>Long Link 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can omit padding from top and bottom of the anchor and use height 100%  `a{height: 100%;}`

```css
#root {
  width: 140px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 30px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  height: auto;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px dotted green;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: lightblue;  
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <ul>
    <li><a>Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a>Long Link 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```